# Is it a requirement to use the image for Raspberry PI linked from the Turtlebot e-manual?

Tags: turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a Turtlebot 3 Burger with a Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB RAM). I see the Turtlebot e-maual provides the [link to a specific Ubuntu image](https://www.robotis.com/service/download.php?no=2064) for Foxy that I could use. Could I just use an Ubuntu Server image for the Raspberry Pi instead, downloaded from Canonical, and then install and configure ROS2 Foxy myself? Or is it necessary to use the ready-made image recommended in the Turtlebot e-manual?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388192/is-it-a-requirement-to-use-the-image-for-raspberry-pi-linked-from-the-turtlebot-e-manual?/) by [fgfanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/50212/fgfanta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use Ubuntu installed yourself if you prefer. However you will need to get and install the ROS software used to communicate with the Turtlebot hardware.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1